# How to get the cell references to update automatically for indirect() function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking to pull data from a different workbooks and have found an excellent workaround in the indirect() function.

`=INDIRECT("'["&$S$14&"]"&$T$14&"'!"&"A8")`

My challenge is that I want this to apply to a few thousand cells with only bit(A8) changing. However, when I do ctrl+d it simply repeats the exact code for every cell.

I want to make sure A8 is just a text value and not a reference to the value IN cell A8 because otherwise I need thousands and thousands of cells with just their name in them. However, making it INTO a text value renders it immune to ctrl+d.

To clarify, I would like each consecutive cell to change to A9,A10,A11 etc

How can I get around this limitation?

Thank you

Comment: I've always found INDIRECT to be a memory intensive function. Copying it to thousands of cells may cause your workbook performance to be poor.

Comment: Thank you fro the answer, I realize I was unclear. I want the A8 value to change with each consecutive cell and be A9, A10, A11. If I remove the final quotation
```=INDIRECT("'["&$S$14&"]"&$T$14&"'!"&"A8)```
then it will do exactly that, however, it will now pull the data in cell A8 and not the text "A8".
This gives me the idea: Is there a way to find and replace every instance of lets say 
```$14&"'!"&"A```
and add a quotation mark after the row number that would follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the column of choice on row 8 and drag down :)

```
=INDIRECT("'["&$S$14&"]"&$T$14&"'!"&"A"&row(A8))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Brilliant!

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I'm allowed to upvote yet.

I have a new challenge maybe you know how to fix. My excel crashed and after reopening it....none of my indirect functions work, even ones I haven't touched in multiple saves. I've tried restarting. Can you think of any way to 'reset'?

Comment: it could be because your recovered file has something along the lines of `(recovered)` in the title but your cell reference doesn't reflect that. Try saving the recovered document(s) as they were and you should be ok.

Comment: I think you might be right. I had to rename the reference with.xlsx and that seemed to refresh the function.